# Spring Webflow Exception-Handler for Action-State

Tags: java, jsf, spring-webflow

I created a Spring Webflow exception-handler for my application and defined it in my abstract parent flow.
In this handler I add FacesMessages to display several errors in a generic way.
Now i got the problem that i can't handle an exception that occures in an action-state. I try to go back to the last valid view-state or something like that (or maybe go to the start-state). Anyway, I don't want the application to crash or show a blank page.

```
@Override
public void handle(FlowExecutionException exception, RequestControlContext context) {
    Object testState = context.getCurrentState();
    if(testState instanceof ActionState){
         //what to do here?
    }
}
```

I am using Spring Webflow Version 2.3.0.RELEASE with JSF 2 on MyFaces.

Best regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute a transition to another state (the transition must exist). So, inside your if statement you could do the following:

```
TransitionDefinition errorDefinition = context.getMatchingTransition("errorState");
Transition errorTransition = (Transition)errorDefinition;
context.execute(errorTransition);
```

The transition could be a global transition to a generic error page.

Regards.